How do you identify the "publisher" property of an executable?
I am trying to create a Windows Defender App Control (WDAC) policy rule to restrict executables by publisher, but I'm not sure what that property actually refers to. Is it the same as the digital signature?
When I right-click and view an executable's Properties, the Digital Signatures tab has an "embedded signatures" section where I can view "Name of signer: XXXXX" (for example, Zoom.exe's name of signer is "Zoom Video Communications, Inc.") Is that the string I would put in the WDAC rule?

It’s the publisher as defined by the certificate

...So, is "Zoom Video Communications, Inc." the string I would input for "Publisher" in WDAC, in that example?
